# How IDP connects to End point application in SSO?

Tags: salesforce, saml, saml-2.0

This is the 1st time I am working in SSO with SAML.And we are going to use the HTTP Post method and the IDP is salesforce. I got below Steps from net.

1. User accesses a custom application for the first time
2. Service Provider Security Filter checks if the security context is available 
   and redirects the user to IDP with a SAML SSO request
3. IDP challenges the user with the authentication dialog and redirects the user to
   Request Assertion Consumer Service (RACS) after the user has authenticated
4. RACS validates the response from IDP, establishes a security context and redirects the user 
   to the original application endpoint
5. Service Provider Security Filter enforces that a valid security context is available and lets the user access the custom application.

Here my Question is IDP needs to authenticate application endpoint. Here the SAML plays between common web page to IDP to initiate SAML request/response. Then how the IDP connect to endpoint? Is that follow any other language to connect and authenticate endpoint? else how it connects? Could you please someone explain the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During configuration of SAML at your Identity Provider, you define an AssertionConsumer endpoint, which is an URL at your application where you expect to receive response from the IDP. After authentication, IDP connects to this endpoint by sending a SAML Response message to it. IDP typically authenticates to the endpoint by digitally signing the SAML message, which you then verify for validity and trust.

The ways of sending SAML messages between IDP and SP (= connecting IDP to the endpoint) are called bindings. Bindings define how exactly to use existing protocols (such as HTTP) to deliver SAML messages, i.e. it tells what parameters should be sent, which HTTP method should be used... Bindings are part of the SAML 2.0 standard and you can find details on how they function in the [SAML 2.0 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf).

The IDP does not directly communicate with the original URL within your application (i.e. the "original application endpoint"). The process of sending user to the correct destination after successful verification of the SAML Response (received at the Assertion Consumer endpoint) can be fully determined by you. For example, in case Assertion Consumer endpoint and the "original application endpoint" are part of the same application and share the security context, you can simply send an HTTP redirect, without need for SAML in this "last mile".

Comment: Thanks for your post. But for my under standing am asking this. pls correct me if i am wrong. So the SAML req/resp will be connected common web page to IDP. And again the SAML req/response will used connect IDP to end point. Is my assumption is correct ?

Comment: Also please let me know, Since endpoint needs to reply back to IDP using SAML response. Is that neccessary to do SAML configuration in end point also ?

Comment: In SP-initialized SSO, your web application only sends one SAML message (AuthnRequest) to the IDP, and IDP sends one SAML message (Response) back to the specified endpoint. So the endpoint doesn't need to send any reply back to IDP. There's also an additional paragraph in the response above, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And you said The process of sending user to the correct destination after successful verification of the SAML Response. Here where the verification comes in ? IDP just generate the SAML response and triggered it to enpoint right ?

Comment: Exactly. IDP generates the SAML Response (and digitally signs it), sends it to the Assertion Consumer endpoint (using one of the bindings, such as HTTP-POST) and the logic inside the Assertion Consumer endpoint then performs the validation (like checking of the signature and all the other checks mandated by the SAML standard).